# Editing elements of a list of tuples based on hamming distance

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
f_list = [('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 34), ('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1), ('AGCTCCCCGGTTTC', 1)]
```

If the hamming distance between any two strings is less than 3, I would like to merge the elements by adding the second entries of each element. If the above condition is not satisfied, I want to keep the element as it is. The output I want is:

```
f_list = [('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 35),('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1)]
```

I have the  function for Hamming distance:

```
def hamming(s1, s2):
   if len(s1) != len(s2):
     raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")  
return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

I used the following to iterate through the list to identify the relevant elements, but I am not sure how to modify the original list:

```
for e in f_list:
    [item for item in f_list if hamming(e[0],item[0]) < 3]

Output: 
[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 34), ('AGCTCCCCGGTTTC', 1)]
[('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1)]
[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 34), ('AGCTCCCCGGTTTC', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

My assumptions are that once an element has been merged, it doesn't need to be checked. I've added three extra elements, one that should match and another that will not match any, and one that will match the first element (so there is an element that has more than one match) to make the test a little bit more robust.

```
import itertools # we'll use islice in case dataset is large and limited memory

def hamming(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))    


f_list = [('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 34), ('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 1), ('GGGGCCCCCAAAAA', 99), 
          ('TGCATTCCTATCTC', 8), ('AGCTCCCCGGTTTC', 1), ('AGCTCCCCGTCTTC', 100)]


def merge_elements(f_list):
    result = []
    flag = [True for _ in f_list]

    for i, seq1 in enumerate(f_list):
        none_close = True
        total = seq1[1]
        for j, seq2 in enumerate(itertools.islice(f_list, i+1, len(f_list))):
            if flag[i+j+1] and hamming(seq1[0],seq2[0]) < 3:
                total += seq2[1]
                none_close = False
                flag[j+i+1] = False
        if flag[i] and none_close:
            result.append(seq1)
        elif flag[i]:
            result.append((seq1[0],total))
    return result


f_list = merge_elements(f_list)
print(f_list)
```

And the result is:

```
[('AGCTCCCCGTTTTC', 135), ('TTCATTCCTCTCTC', 9), ('GGGGCCCCCAAAAA', 99)]
```